# Flutter: Can I make Navigation bar top left and right top with radius 20

Tags: android, flutter

Flutter: Can I make Navigation bar top left and right top with radius 20
I tried custom bottom nav.

Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.blue, // Set your desired background color
borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
topRight: Radius.circular(20),
),
),

But it is not working

Answer (score 3):

try with the [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) Widget surrounding your navigation nar, there is an example:

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
    ),
    child: Container(), /*Here goes your navigation bar*/
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the `BottomNavigationBar` in a `ClipRRect` with the desired border radius.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
ClipRRect _getBtmNavBar() {
 return ClipRRect(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
  topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
),
child: BottomNavigationBar(
  currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
  onTap: _onTabTapped,
  selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
  selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
), ); }
```